# Hibernate error: session.get()

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, session, get

I am using Hibernate in my NetBeans project and when I try to get result set from Oracle database with following code:

```
Client c = (Client) session.get(Client.class, id);
```

i get the following error:

```
javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mb.MBObavestenje.pronadjiKlijenta(MBObavestenje.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:278)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 28 more
```

I get null pointer exception when I try to use this object c.toString().

It seems like this .get() function won't return object of Client class. I have been struggling with this problem for 3 days now, can anyone help?

Code in the line 118 refers to the ManagedBean and it says:

```
System.out.println(c.getName());
```

Here is the method which is problematic:

```
public CLient getClient(String id){
   Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
   session.beginTransaction();
   Client c = (Client) session.get(Client.class, id);
   session.getTransaction().commit();
   return c;
}
```

Also, when I tried to do

```
System.out.println(c.getName())
```

method after commit it also reported NullPointerException.

Comment: What is the line of code at line 118 of MBObavestenje.java? Show us the relevant code.

Comment: It is a line from ManagedBean where I am trying to get info from object c:System.out.println(c.getName());

Comment: Post the relevant code in the question. Not in comments.

Comment: All we can say from the single line of code you posted is that the exception is caused by `c` being null. So, either you haven't called session.get() before, or you have called it but with an ID that doesn't exist in the database, or some code has reset c to null since you have called it. But without code, we can only make guesses. Use your debugger.

Comment: I updated the question with the code, can you take a look now?

Comment: No. The code you posted wouldn't even compile, and the code you posted doesn't contain the line that throws the exception. So we still have no idea where you call the method you posted, how the `c` variable is initialized. Have you tried using your debugger? Check if the method is called, check the value of id, check the returned value, check what happens between the method call and the line causing the exception? You realize that Session.get() does return null if the ID doesn't exist in the database, right?